# What does undertake means in the following context? Dos it means to start?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law

In the terms and condition of a building company is written:

**Company is responsible for planning consent.  All other consents reasonably required by the Company to undertake the contract shall be the responsibility of the customer.  If the Customer fails to obtain any such consents and the company suffers loss as a result, including any loss of profit, the customer shall be liable to the Company for such losses.’**

Can company start the work without party wall consent, because the customer has been responsible but did not obtain it?

Answer (score 4):

> What does undertake means in the following context?

*A priori* it means to perform [the contract], to do the construction work. There is no indication in that paragraph that all consents are required *prior to* starting the work.

> Can company start the work without party wall consent, because the customer has been responsible but did not obtain it?

This depends on the technicalities of the construction profession as well as the project schedule. To a person with no construction background and no context of the project it is unclear whether the building company even needs to start with/nearby that wall.

If consent is unavailable by the time the company *reasonably* needs it (for instance, because thereby it was "compelled" to reschedule or because an inspector fined the company for not providing proof of consent), the clause entitles the company to recover from you that loss.

Comment: Note that "party wall consent" has a very specific meaning in the UK.

Comment: @JBentley "*"party wall consent" has a very specific meaning in the UK.*" Yes, the term comes from the [Party Wall etc. Act 1996](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/40/contents). The substance of the answer is the same, though. For instance, the reference to "*nearby* [that wall]" in the answer relates to the criteria of "*within a distance of three metres*", "*of six metres*" in section 6

Comment: The point is that the OP is asking *who* is responsible for meeting the obligations under the Party Wall Act, as opposed to under what circumstances they are responsible. OP wants to know if the company can go ahead on the basis that (in their contract) the customer is responsible for dealing with the consent. The starting point to that is that the Act places obligations on the "building owner". However, it seems likely to me that the company will commit a trespass if it proceeds anyway, albeit it may be able to hold the customer liable under the terms of the contract.

Comment: @JBentley "*the customer is responsible for dealing with the consent.*" It is unclear from the OP's description whether *planning consent* means neighbor's consent or regulator's/architect's approval of the construction project. I interpret it as the latter, and thus independent of the party wall consent. "*it seems likely to me that the company will commit a trespass*". It will not if the company works outside the neighbor's property, something that is unclear. That is, in part, why I wrote "*This depends on the technicalities of the construction profession as well as the project schedule*".

Comment: Remember this is tagged UK. "Planning consent" in the UK refers to permission granted by a local authority under [s 57(1) of the Town and Country Planning Act 1990](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/8/section/57). Working on a party wall without party wall consent is a trespass under UK law. It doesn't matter whether you enter the neighbour's property or not.

Comment: See for example Seeff v Ho [2011] EWCA Civ 186 (particularly paragraphs 35 and 36) for a trespass case involving a breach of the Party Wall Act requirements.